# Remove latin1 chars from a file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

My file is utf8 but contains several latin1 chars namely other foreign languages. My aim is to get rid of these chars using a Unix command. Earlier when i tried to achieve this by removing all the non-ASCII chars, the below command went ahead and removed all the accented chars as well. I wanted to retain the accented chars on the same hand i wanted to remove only the non-english(mandarain, japanese, korean, thai, arabic) terms from the file.

```
grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" file.txt  -> this command helped me remove non-ASCII chars but it also removes the accented chars(í, æ, Ö etc)...is it possible to get


888|Jobin|Matt|NORMALSQ|YUOZ|IOP|OPO|洁|ID12|doorbell|geo@xyx.comd
1011|ICE|LAND|邵|DUY|DUY|123|EOP|dataset1|geo@xyx.com
53101|炜|GUTTI|RR|Hi|London|UK|WLU|GB|dataset1|陈
สัอ |JOH|LIU|ABC|DUY|DUY|57T2P|EOP|unknown|geo@xyx.com
เมื่รกเริ่ม|JOH|LIU|ABC|DUYសា|DUY|57T2P|EOP|unknown|geo@xyx.com
|| RAVI|OLE|Hi|London|UK|NA|GB|unknown| WELSH@WELSH.COM
Rogério|Davies|Hi|USA|US|WLU|US|unknown| USA@WELSH.COM
Balázs| Roque| Hi|USA|US|WLU|US|unknown| USA@WELSH.COM
Johny|Peniç| Hi|USA|US|WLU|US|unknown| USA@WELSH.COM
 Mike|Mane| Hi | USA |US|WLU|US|unknown| USA@WELSH.COM
```

Output:

```
888|Jobin|Matt|NORMALSQ|YUOZ|IOP|OPO||ID12|doorbell|geo@xyx.comd
1011|ICE|LAND||DUY|DUY|57T2P|EOP|dataset1|geo@xyx.com
53101||GUTTI|RR|Hi|London|UK|WLU|GB|dataset1|
 |JOH|LIU|ABC|DUY|DUY|57T2P|EOP|unknown|geo@xyx.com
 |JOH|LIU|ABC|DUY|DUY|57T2P|EOP|unknown|geo@xyx.com
|| RAVI|OLE|Hi|London|UK|NA|GB|unknown| WELSH@WELSH.COM
Rogério|Davies|Hi|USA|US|WLU|US|unknown| USA@WELSH.COM
Balázs| Roque| Hi|USA|US|WLU|US|unknown| USA@WELSH.COM
Johny|Peniç| Hi|USA|US|WLU|US|unknown| USA@WELSH.COM
Mike|Mane| Hi | USA |US|WLU|US|unknown| USA@WELSH.COM
```

Comment: There are only four possibilities: you have a Latin1 file, or you have an UTF-8 file, or you have information which describes which parts of the file have which encoding, or you have corrupted data. I suspect your case is the last one. Latin1 characters in an UTF-8 file will often be recognisable as encoding errors, but they can also form valid UTF-8 sequences. Also, what does "Op" mean?

Comment: Sounds like you want to remove any chars that are not letters and those not ASCII. Try `perl -i -CSD -Mutf8 -pe 's/[^\p{L}[:ascii:]]+//g' filename`.

Comment: @Amadan My file has 1M recs and these sorts of pesky recs are just a handful. Is there a way to handle latin1 chars in UTF8?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately my Unix terminal doesn't contain a perl utility.

Comment: Try `LANG=C sed -i 's/[^[:alpha:]\d000-\d127]//g' file.txt`

Comment: I'm a bit convinced that "Ravi" "Ole" is not his real name ;-)

Comment: No Perl? What kind of Unix is that?

Comment: @choroba Perl isn't available everywhere, some UNIX boxes only come with standard UNIX tools and can't have anything else, including perl, added to them. That was the case at my previous job and we do see people stating that's their current situation in questions once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Unicode Properties to detect characters that belong to the Latin and Basic Latin, which are the ones you seem to want preserved. Perl supports them in regular expressions:

```
perl -CSD -pe 's/[^\p{Basic Latin}\p{Latin}]//g' file.txt
```

(but it doesn't change `123` to `57T2P`)

- `-CSD` turns on UTF-8 decoding/encoding of input and output
- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints each line after processing
- `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/g` is a global replacement, it replaces all occurrences of PATTERN by the replacement, in this case the replacement is empty
- `[...]` introduces a character class, `^` at the beginning negates it, i.e. we want to match anything that's *not* Latin or Basic Latin.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have UTF-8 and want to keep only the extended ascii characters (aka, usually, latin1), `iconv` may work for you.

```
iconv -c -f UTF8 -t LATIN1 input_file > output_file
```

> > > -c     Silently discard characters that cannot be converted instead
> > >                     of terminating when encountering such characters.

Comment: I'm guessing they want to preserve the data in UTF-8; if so, you need to convert back with `iconv -f latin1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most non-elegant solution to your problem:

```
$ sed -e 's/[^,./@|[:space:]0-9[=a=][=b=][=c=][=d=][=e=][=f=][=g=][=h=][=i=][=j=][=k=][=l=][=m=][=n=][=o=][=p=][=q=][=r=][=s=][=t=][=u=][=v=][=w=][=x=][=y=][=z=][=A=][=B=][=C=][=D=][=E=][=F=][=G=][=H=][=I=][=J=][=K=][=L=][=M=][=N=][=O=][=P=][=Q=][=R=][=S=][=T=][=U=][=V=][=W=][=X=][=Y=][=Z=]]//g' file.txt
```

To my big surprise I could not use `[:punct:]` because some of the symbols are actually defined as punctuation.